# Sign character background not the same the the column background

Tags: vim, color-scheme

In my vim the signs character background is not the same that the SignColumn background.

It is quite disruptive, so what could I do to correct it ?
Is there any particular `:highlight` command to change my signs background and to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sign is defined to use a specific syntax highlight group for its text. See `:help :sign-define`. Find where the sign is defined, check the "texthl" part of it, and either change that part or change the highlight attributes of that highlight group.